# three.js: At a certain distance the entire scene goes dark in shadow

Tags: three.js

In this example you can zoom in and out with the mouse wheel. If you keep zooming out and keep making the scene smaller it eventually goes completely dark. Is there any way to stop it doing that?
I thought maybe the range of the light is the problem but the default is set to go on forever so I don't know what's causing it.

```js
width = window.innerWidth
height = window.innerHeight

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(width, height)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

scene = new THREE.Scene()
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, width / height, 0.1, 3000)
camera.position.set(-45, 47, 75)
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera)
controls.minDistance = 40
controls.maxDistance = 1300
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 75})

scene.add(camera, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.4))
light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8)

renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap
light.castShadow = true
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 3072
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 3072
light.shadow.camera.left = 500

function shadow(w) {
  w.castShadow = true
  w.receiveShadow = true
}

camera.add(light)
light.position.y += 60
light.position.x += 70

requestAnimationFrame(function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
})

b = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20), material)
shadow(b)
scene.add(b)

c = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5,5,10,32), material)
c.position.set(3,15,3)
shadow(c)
scene.add(c)

d = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 10, 1), material)
d.position.set(3,15,-5)
shadow(d)
scene.add(d)
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem by increasing the `far` property of the light`s internal shadow camera. Try something like:

```
 light.shadow.camera.far = 3000
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.